# Finding joint PMF given $X \sim Bernoulli(\frac{1}{3})$ and $Y = 4x-2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If we know that $X  \sim Bernoulli(\frac{1}{3})$ and $Y = 4x-2$. Then, how can we find the set of $x,y$ coordinates, that give us non-zero probability, and write their probability?

I know that since $X  \sim Bernoulli(\frac{1}{3}) \implies$ $X = 0, 1$, and so the coordinates that give us non-zero probability would be $(0, -2)$ and $(1, 2)$. However, how can I find the probabilities corresponding to these coordinates? That is, $p_{X,Y}(0, -2)$ and $p_{X,Y}(1, 2)$?

Also, after doing some more digging I found that $p_{X,Y}(x,y) = p_{X}(x)$ when $Y = -2, 2$. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $Y=4X-2$, The probability of a specific coordinate $(x,y)$ is the same as the probability a $X=x$ if $y=4x-2$ and 0 anywhere else.

$$P(X=x,Y=y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{lcl} 
P(X=x) & if & y=4x-2\\ 
0 & if & y\neq 4x-2
\end{array}\right.$$

Afterall, $$\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl} 
P(X=0,Y=-2) & = & P(X=0) = 2/3\\ 
P(X=1,Y=2) & = & P(X=1) = 1/3\\ 
P(X=x,Y=y) & = & 0, \text{anywhere else}.
\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

The only values of $(X;Y)$ support are $(0;-2)$ and $(1;2)$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$, respectively